# How to configure AGOL popup to open local files (PDF\JPEG)?

Tags: arcgis-online, popup, hyperlink

I'm trying to enrich my AGOL application by adding a hyperlink to ancillary documents that I have, on a permanent path at my local machine.

The question is this:

Is it possible to configure AGOL popup with HTML code to enable open files from local machine?

I've tried adding the path based on a the software's configuration wizard. Trying to insert an additional HTML prefix:

`<a href="file path"{file_Name_Field} download target="_blank">Click here to download</a>`

Doing so makes the browser open the path with my AGOL home page URL before the path and hence the document isn't opening.
It seems that ESRI blocked this option in order to increase credits use.

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue? I am interested in doing precisely this.

Comment: Did you ever get a working solution?
I'am interested in doing same.

Comment: Have you considered hosting the file elsewhere and linking it from there?  You could probably find some free storage site or one that is at least cheaper than ESRI credits.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to store your auxiliary files as attachments for the served feature layer.  Here are a couple of links that highlight this setup:

[An overview of the Attachments toolset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000015m000000)

[Configure pop-ups](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/configure-pop-ups.htm) (Show attachments section)

Comment: The problem is that files is quite big (about 15 GB). That means it will consume all of my credits by far.
Any other suggestions other than this?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a long standing issue, and it's still the same way. Since ArcGIS Online can only allow https:// connections it won't recognize file:/// .
My solution was to drop all the files into a Google Drive, then use a script I found on YouTube to build an index spreadsheet that has the original file name and the Google Drive access URL. Then I added a field to the data, made a relate to the table, and copied over all the URLs. It's the long way to row the boat around the lake, but it worked.